# How to I show a category list on inner pages in Magento?

Tags: magento

In the Magento theme I am using there is a left sidebar, on the homepage the sidebar contains a category list but on inner pages (category page, product page, etc) the list isn't there. How can I replicate this block onto the product and category page so that users can choose a category from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the block in the layout(catalog.xml) under the section

1. Product view

> ```
>   <catalog_product_view translate="label">
>   <reference name="left">
>     Your block comes here
>    </reference>
> </catalog_product_view></li>
> ```
>
> Category Page
>
> > ```
> >  <catalog_category_default translate="label">
> >     <reference name="left">
> >       Your block comes here
> >     </reference>
> >    </catalog_category_default></li>
> > ```
> >
> > Otherwise just put in the deafult section of the catalog.xml, I am thinking that should also work.
> >
> > > ```
> > >    <default>
> > >      <reference name="left">
> > >       Your block comes here
> > >       </reference>
> > >   </default>
> > > ```
> > >
> > > I think the block that ususally displays the left navigation of category is
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >   <reference name="left">
> > > >     <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency"         template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
> > > >     </reference>
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > Hope this helps you to some extent.
> > > >         Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I'm having some trouble locating the proper section in my catalog.xml would you mind taking a look? The contents are too long to post so: http://pastebin.com/vyrH4u94

Comment: Paste                                                                  <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency"         template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>                             
     after line 83                                                             & paste <reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency"         template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>                                                                          after line 238

Comment: That added a new box that allows for price/color sorting but not the list of categories as shown on the homepage :( Do I need to change the reference name?

Comment: The sorting you're talking about (layered navigation in Magento world) is certainly here instead of the category listing you expected because you are certainly using "catalog.leftnav" as name attribute for your block. catalog.leftnav is also the name of the layered navigation block which thus is conflicting with your category list block.